# conversion from type 'datarowview' to type 'string' is not valid ” for combobox

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm working with a database, and I have two problems with my add form and edit form.

My first problem is with my add form. I keep getting an error

> Conversion from type 'DataRowView' to type 'String' is not valid

I've bolded where I keep getting the error message. This is my code under my add form:

```vb
Public Class Add_New_University
Public Property universityid As Integer
Private myuniversities As New University

Private Sub Add_New_University_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' TODO: This line of code loads data into the '_UniversityCourses_MDFDataSet.University' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.UniversityTableAdapter.Fill(Me._UniversityCourses_MDFDataSet.University)

End Sub

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    'NOTE: Exception thrown on this line.
    If myuniversities.Insert((txtuniversity.Text), CStr(cbo1.SelectedValue), CStr(cbo2.SelectedValue), (txttuition.Text)) Then
        Me.Close()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot update the University table.")
    End If
End Sub

' closes the form
Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

My second problem is in my edit form: I wrote a try catch that's supposed to update the entered info into the dgv, or it throws an error

> Cannot update the university table.

I keep getting else message, and nothings being added to my dgv.

This is my code for my edit form:

```vb
Public Class EditUniversity
Public Property UniversityId As Integer
Private myuniversities As New University

Private Sub EditUniversity_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' TODO: This line of code loads data into the '_UniversityCourses_MDFDataSet.University' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.UniversityTableAdapter.Fill(Me._UniversityCourses_MDFDataSet.University)

End Sub

' Save Button 
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' Validate input
    If txtuniversity.Text = "" Or IsNumeric(txtuniversity.Text) = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid university name.")
        txtuniversity.Clear()
        txtuniversity.Focus()
    ElseIf txttuition.Text = "" Or IsNumeric(txttuition.Text) = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid amount.")
        txttuition.Clear()
        txttuition.Focus()
    End If

    Try
        myuniversities.Update(UniversityId, CStr(txtuniversity.Text), CStr(cbo1.SelectedItem), CStr(cbo2.SelectedItem), CDec(txttuition.Text))
        Me.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show("Cannot update the University table.")
    End Try

End Sub

'Close Button
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

End Class
```

If anyone could help me understand what I'm doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: "I have two problems with my add form and edit form". Then please create two separate threads, each with a title that summarises one issue and a question that provides all the information relevant to that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to address the first issue, given that it relates to the title of this question, and ignore the second, which should be moved to another thread with an appropriate title.

The fact that the `SelectedValue` property is returning the same as the `SelectedItem` property indicates that you have not set the `ValueMember` property.  Just as the `DisplayMember` specifies the `DataColumn` of the bound `DataTable` the data should be drawn from to display in control, so the `ValueMember` specifies the `DataColumn` the data should be drawn from to expose via the `SelectedValue`.

That said, if you just want the text displayed in the control then you can use the `Text` property.  Usually, though, you would display a user-friendly column, e.g. a name or description, and then access the corresponding primary key value via the `SelectedValue`.